# Вывод таблицы через XSL

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

Есть XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Authors.xsl"?>
<catalog>
    <author>Petrov, Petr</author>
    <author>Ivanov, Ivan</author>
    <author>Andreev, Andrey</author>
    <book id="bk101">
        <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
        <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
        <genre>Computer</genre>
        <price>44.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
        <description>An in-depth look at creating applications
            with XML.</description>
    </book>
    <book id="bk102">
        <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
        <title>Midnight Rain</title>
        <genre>Fantasy</genre>
        <price>5.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
        <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies,
            an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen
            of the world.</description>
    </book>`
```

Необходимо вывести таблицу, с заголовками и двумя столбцами: авторы католога и авторы книг. Строки могут повторяться и нельзя использовать for-each.

```
Пока додумался до такого 

    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="catalog/book">
        <HTML>
            <BODY>
                <TABLE border="1" >
                    <TR >
                        <TD width = "500"><xsl:apply-templates select="author" /></TD>
                        <TD width = "500"><xsl:apply-templates select="../author" /></TD>
                    </TR>
                </TABLE>
            </BODY>
        </HTML>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Но как можно добавить заголовки к столбацам, чтобы они не повторялись каждый раз?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

должно получиться что-то типа этого, только надо добавить заголовки

Comment: У вас явно не видно, как автор каталога относится к автору книг, уточните этот момент.

Comment: Есть авторы составившие каталог книг, у книг есть свои авторы, это все, особо они никак друг к другу не относятся.

Comment: Тогда боюсь, что ответа на ваш вопрос нету. Вам нужно формулу соотношения прописать в `select="сюда"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно создать два шаблона. В шаблоне `catalog` сформировать таблицу и вывести заголовки, а потом из него вызвать шаблон `book`, который обработает каждую книгу

```xslt
<xsl:template match="catalog">
  <HTML>
    <BODY>
      <TABLE border="1">
        <TR>
          <TD width="500">Автор книги</TD>
          <TD width="500">Автор каталога</TD>
        </TR>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="book" />
      </TABLE>
    </BODY>
  </HTML>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="book">
  <TR>
    <TD width="500">
      <xsl:value-of select="author" />
    </TD>
    <TD width="500">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="../author" />
    </TD>
  </TR>
</xsl:template>
```

P.S. Для повышения производительности, список авторов каталога лучше отдать в `book` параметром